# Tensorflow how to check if a tensor row is only zeroes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a simple network for predicting bounding box coordinates of a single object. There are however pictures where there is no object to be found. Since the network always makes a prediction, it also predicts a confidence value between 0 and 1 which should indicate the probability that there is an object in the picture. My tensor with the predictions is called `logits` and it's a `(batch_size, 5)` tensor (confidence, x, y, width and height). Similarly the `labels` tensor is also `(batch_size, 5)`.

Previously I was training only with images that always had an object, so I could basically do

`loss = tf.l2_loss(logits - labels)`

I want to start training also with pictures with no objects and when there is no object in the picture, I don't want the network to be penalized for whichever coordinates it predicted. In this case all that matters is the confidence value, which should be close to 0 (no object).

How should I structure my labels and loss function to accomplish this? I can set the label of images with  no objects to all zeroes, but how do I check that a particular row is only zeroes? And in that case, the corresponding row in the logits needs also to be set to zeroes (except the confidence value!) so that the loss incurred because of the coordinates is also zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach to find if a row of a tensor is all zero:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image = tf.fill([8,8], 0)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
image_row = tf.slice(image, [1,0], [1, -1])
total = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(image_row))
is_all_zero = tf.equal(total, 0)
print sess.run([total, is_all_zero, image_row])
```

Result:

```
[0, True, array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: This solves OP's problem but does not actually check if the row is all zero, but that the sum is zero. A row might contain `[100, -100,0,0,0]` and this will sum to zero. If you switched a few things around, then it could be made to work consistently in other scenarios and match title of OP's question more accurately.

Comment: Take the absolute value first

Comment: Thanks, added the abs operator to fix the case.

Comment: A more explicit option in the current version of TensorFlow (r1.1) is  `tf.logical_not(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(image,0),axis=0))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tf.math.count_nonzero()` to check whether the tensor has all zeros or not. You can check the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/count_nonzero).